# issues writing simple sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have recently started working with SQL and I am trying to write a query that will display all cities that has the highest volume and listing on a yearly basis.

this query is able to handle the year 2011 alone

```
select city, year, month,max(volume),max(listings) 
from kaydata 
where year = 2011
```

result

```
    city    year    month   max(volume) max(listings)
 0  Abilene 2011    2       6505000.0     746.0
```

sample data

```
    city    year    month   volume      listings    
0   modak   2011    1      5380000.0    701.0   
1   Abilene 2011    2      6505000.0    746.0   
2   ipetu   2010    3      9285000.0    784.0
2   oyog    2010    4      7085000.0    204.0
```

desired result

```
    city    year    month   max(volume) max(listings)
 0  Abilene 2011    2       6505000.0     746.0
 1  ipetu   2010    3       9285000.0     784.0
```

Comment: Can not  use group by year?

Comment: The desired result cannot be obtained from your sample data. Your sample data does not include the values contained in the desired result, which means you've posted useless sample data.

Comment: The actual data is long... the sample is just there for demonstration purposes

Comment: It's nice to have sample data that can be worked to produce the desired output for verification of code. Should provide numbers that can reconcile.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this would achieve what you're after:

```
select city,year,month,volume,maxlisting from (
  select * , row_number() over (partition by year order by volume desc) rn 
  , max(listing) over (partition by year) maxlisting 
  from kaydata
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Please can you check the updated question. Also your code did not work and I also did not understand it

Comment: @lee your sample output doesn't make sense to me , you are choosing the row with maximum volume in a specific year but showing max(listing) in that year which doesn't belong to that row. is that correct? if that's what you want , see updated answer